# Intellitrace: IIS could not be found on the machine

Tags: iis-6, visual-studio-2012, intellitrace

OK.
Here's what I am running:

- Intellitrace Collector (powershell 2.0, from VS 2012)
- Windows Server 2003, running IIS 6
- The target application to be traced is a web service (asmx, ASP.NET 2.0.50727)

Here's what I've done & what happened:

```
cmdlet Start-IntelliTraceCollection at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
OutputPath: logs
Start-IntelliTraceCollection : An error occurred during website instrumentation
: Internet Information Services could not be found on the machine.
At line:1 char:29
+ Start-IntelliTraceCollection <<<<  MyAppPool .\collection_plan.ASP.NE
T.trace.xml
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Start-IntelliTraceCollection]
   , IISLegacyVersionException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise.WebInstrument.
   IISLegacyVersionException,Microsoft.VisualStudio.IntelliTrace.PowerShell.S
  tartIntelliTraceCollectionCommand
```

I tried running powershell as administrator - it didn't help (same error message)

Am I missing something here ?

Is any of the components I mentioned not supported ? ie: version of IIS, version of Windows Server ? I am suspicious that the IIS version isn't supported (`IISLegacyVersionException` was raised)

Much appreciated for your time + attention.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Microsoft page on collecting IntelliTrace data from IIS using the standalone collector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh398365.aspx) using VS2012 mentions

ASP.NET Web apps hosted on Internet Information Services (IIS) version 7.0, 7.5, and 8.0

as a requirement, so you're right, IIS6 is not supported.